# Unable to load DLL 'UNRAR.DLL': The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, reference, unrar

I just downloaded UnRAR.dll from http://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm package includes C# sample project when I run in VS 2010 after selecting .rar file for extract I am getting below error message

[image: Unable to load 'UNRAR.DLL']

and when I add reference unrar.dll I am getting below error

[image: unrar.dll could not be loaded]

Please help / point me what I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UnRAR.dll is not a .NET assembly so it cannot be used as a project reference.

It is a native DLL so you'll have to use P/Invoke to access its methods or write a C++/CLI wrapper around it.

There's some sample code in [this MSDN forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/022a0806-bb30-4cea-b446-bc20c7dd4838/) that should provide a decent starting place and show the necessary approach.

There also appears to be a fairly complete [wrapper](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid46740BBD1043E2B3CFAE822BF64B747E042CD2F2.aspx?s=file#L43) included in the [Blue Mirror CD/DVD Indexer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/octoindex/) project.

---

It should also be noted the [SevenZipSharp](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/) includes support for this out-of-the-box. I haven't used it myself, but it might be worth checking into.

Comment: You might want to consider explaining how he can import the DLL into his project.

Comment: @DeviantSeev - Added a link to some code that someone else is using to access UnRAR.dll.

Comment: @M.Babcock Thanks I checked mentioned links same wrapper is included in an example project from same author,however as mentioned by Mr.Steve "unrar.dll" should be in BIN\DEBUG folder I just copied the .dll but if I compile and run .exe from BIN\DEBUG its working fine but if I Debug its throwing error "Error while trying to run projectcould not load file or assembly 'unrar' or one of its dependencies.The module was expected to contain an assebly manifest" ... if I remove .dll from BIN\DEBUG the project run in debug mode throwing same error as I attached picture

Answer (score 2):

The sample you are talking about use

```
[DllImport("unrar.dll")]
```

to access the functions inside the library.

This DLL should be visible when the test project runs.
So you should copy it into the BIN\DEBUG folder or in a 
folder where your project runs.

Comment: I just copied the .dll but if I compile and run .exe from BIN\DEBUG its working fine but if I Debug its throwing error "Error while trying to run projectcould not load file or assembly 'unrar' or one of its dependencies.The module was expected to contain an assebly manifest" ... if I remove .dll from BIN\DEBUG the project run in debug mode throwing same error as I attached picture

Comment: I'm not sure, but I have just tried on my PC and there was problems because the "unrar.dll" is a 32 bit project. The default for the project is AnyCPU and my OS is Win64bit. So the dll will not be loaded with a BadImageFormatException. Changed to x86 configuration and everything run fine.